# Swagger not working correctly through Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, swagger

We are developing web application in our class, and one of the tasks is to configure swagger for documentation. I did it, and it works perfectly. However, next we had to configure nginx and now when sending request with swagger through nginx it isn't requesting correct url (it requests http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/albums/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:82/api/v1/albums/)

```
This is my config for swagger
location /api/v1/swagger/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

(I am developing web app with django, for swagger i'm using drf_yasg)

I tried adding 'API_URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:82/api/v1/', in my SWAGGER SETTINGS in Django but it didn't fix anything